# Mysql update only records with a unquie field value - how to?

Tags: mysql

Say I have an mysql table:

```
ID, Name, Number
1, abc, 0
2, def, 0
3, def, 0
4, ghi, 0
```

I now want to change the value of the field 'Number' (say to 1) in all records where the field 'Name' has a value that appears only once (in this case record 1 and record 4). How do I do that in mysql the simplest possible way?

I am an mysql beginner and have googled this problem a lot, but found no solution - at least not a solution simple enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL, you need to use a JOIN on your update query:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Name
                           FROM yourtable
                           GROUP BY Name
                           HAVING COUNT(*)=1) t2
  ON t1.Name=t2.Name
SET
  Number=1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ed1b/1). Or you need to use a nested subquery:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET Number=1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM yourtable 
             GROUP BY name 
             HAVING COUNT(*)=1) s)
```

(Please notice the `SELECT * FROM (...your subquery...)`. Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f0f/1).

Comment: Thank you so much to all, including editors. In the end fthiella's answer made it work for me :-). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

its a simple  please try with mysql

```
update  [tablename] set number=1 
where id in (select id 
  from [tablename] 
  group by name 
  having count()=1) )
```

My syntax may be little wrong you can try playing with them. 
Nested query will solve this and you will be able to get the results seamless

Good luck 
if you need any help then do let me know I will write exact query and give you.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest way would be to use a subquery:

```
UPDATE mytable AS NumberUpdating SET Number = 42 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Number AS NumberTesting
    WHERE
        NumberTesting.ID != NumberUpdating.ID AND
        NumberTesting.Name == NumberUpdating.Name
)
```

It's more obvious what this is doing, but it may not be as performant as a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE FROM mytables AS NumberUpdating
LEFT JOIN mytable AS NumberTesting ON
    NumberTesting.Name == NumberUpdating.name AND
    NumberTesting.ID != NumberUpdating.ID
WHEN NumberTesting.ID IS NULL
SET Number = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) GROUP BY Name)` gives you table with unique names and count for number of occurrences of Name.

```
UPDATE (SELECT ID, COUNT(name) GROUP BY Name)
SET Number = 1
WHERE COUNT(name) = 1
```

Did not test though, but hope it guides you to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
UPDATE Yourtable SET number=1 where ID in (Select id,count(name) as num from Yourtable group by name having num=1)
```